# Create polygon from set of points distributed

Tags: r, polygon, point

I need help on the R language

from my code:

```
inter1= read.table("C:/inter.csv", header=TRUE)
inter1$xx<-inter1$long
inter1$yy<-inter1$lat
coordinates(inter1) = ~long + lat
#Plot the results:
plot(inter1)
```

I had this plot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/98aTf.png

I'm looking now for each set of points on the plot draw a polygon, I do not know the process i must prceder to get there, thank you for your help

inter.csv:

```
long    lat var1.pred
1   4.2 19  31.8216045615229
2   4.3 19  31.913824396486
3   4.4 19  32.0090783396173
4   4.5 19  32.1067681024233
5   4.6 19  32.2061094352961
6   4.7 19  32.3061148156713
7   4.8 19  32.4055837134796
8   4.9 19  32.503104196147
9   5   19  32.5970697606984
10  5.1 19  32.6857147918646
11  5.2 19  32.767170733855
12  5.3 19  32.8395428348418
13  5.4 19  32.9010042955024
14  5.5 19  32.9499012300441
15  5.6 19  32.9848587133105
16  5.7 19  33.004876178167
17  5.8 19  33.0094002932703
18  5.9 19  32.998365567474
19  6   19  32.9721970820907
20  6.1 19  32.9317751315546
21  6.2 19  32.8783669584517
22  6.3 19  32.8135349988031
23  6.4 19  32.7390332831422
24  6.5 19  32.6567036402505
```

Comment: does your table contains a column identifying each set of points?

Comment: no,observation are all in a single table, as follows : i edited my post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, one solution is to pass by an intermediate rasterization, and then polygonize it. Polygons can be smoothed for better visualization. See below the code

```
inter1= read.table("inter.csv", header=TRUE)

#add a category (required for later rasterizing/polygonizing)
inter1 <- cbind(inter1, cat = rep(1L, nrow(inter1)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#convert to spatial points
coordinates(inter1) = ~long + lat

#gridify your set of points
gridded(inter1) <- TRUE

#convert to raster
r <- raster(inter1)

#convert raster to polygons
sp = rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = T)

#addition transformation to distinguish well the set of polygons
polys <- slot(sp@polygons[[1]], "Polygons")
output <- SpatialPolygons(
  Srl = lapply(1:length(polys),
               function(x){
                 p <- polys[[x]]

                 #applying spline.poly function for smoothing polygon edges
                 px <- slot(polys[[x]], "coords")[,1]
                 py <- slot(polys[[x]], "coords")[,2]
                 bz <- spline.poly(slot(polys[[x]], "coords"),100, k=3)
                 bz <- rbind(bz, bz[1,])
                 slot(p, "coords") <- bz               

                 # create Polygons object
                 poly <- Polygons(list(p), ID = x)
                 return(poly)
               }),
  proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
)

#plot
plot(sp, border = "gray", lwd = 2) #polygonize result
plot(output, border = "red",  add = TRUE) #smoothed polygons
```

[image: smoothed_polygons]

Note: You have long/lat coordinates (crs = EPSG:4326), so i made the example so you can see where to specify the projection of your spatial polygons, during its construction. If you didn't specify the `proj4string` at this time, you can still do it after creating `output` object doing `proj4string(output) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")`

Comment: thank you very much for your proposal, but I have to find a way to separate sets of point 
otherwise is what can create a raster from these points?

Comment: yes, i thought you would have a column to cluster, but i've seen your comment afterwhile. Not sure rasterizing could be doable. i'm going to check if clustering can be of help.

Comment: can you please attach a link to the entire dataset to test clustering? thanks

Comment: how I can attach the csv file please ,I didn't find the option

Comment: there's no file hosting. You should use another one (e.g. pastebin, dropbox) and paste the link.

Comment: ok, from your screenshot, i see you did a selection based on the ``var1.pred`` variable, it does not correspond to ``plot(inter1)``, please update it with the right filter you set.

Comment: I'm sorry here is the correct link https://www.dropbox.com/s/6alyxvagfkvpvyc/inter.csv?dl=0

Comment: i've edited my answer, please check. hope this helps

Comment: thank's very very much, you saved my life
a question please , is't possible to onverting lines On a polygon to a spline?

Comment: i can suggest you ``gSimplify`` from ``rgeos`` (see my update above). they might be other tools (i keep update if i see something better). if it solves your problem, please leave a vote

Comment: thank's a lot again, I continue to look for the spline 
ps: I cann't vote, they told me that I need 15 reputation to be able to vote

Comment: last question if I may please, how to save it as shapefiles?

Comment: For smoothing polygons, look to my last update above: you can use Bezier curve, it gives quite good results. For exporting shapefiles, use ``writeOGR`` from ``rgdal``. Vote when you'll have the rights ;-)

Comment: I return you , after I changed my datasets and wanted to plot several on the same card; 

here is my datasetes: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jaixyn6jwkec549/inter1.csv?dl=0 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1fwv3e5pthm2uw/inter2.csv?dl=0 

look what I obletnue, 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxbuqxrrs0knatg/plot1.png?dl=0 
for the plot in red there is no problem, but for the pad in blue I will not why there is such a regtangle comes out. 

any idea? ps:i've edited my post

Comment: I've update the code relying on contributed function ``spline.poly`` given here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/how-to-smooth-the-polygons-in-a-contour-map/24929#24929 This replaces the Bezier-based smoothing

Comment: thansk,I posted a new problem in R that I encountered here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118286/its-possible-to-create-a-scatterplot-with-icons-svg-ou-png-instead-of-points  is what you can take a look please?