# Calculate area of "hand-drawn" polygon in R

Tags: r, coordinates, polygon, area

I have a series of coordinates that represent a hand-drawn polygon. At the intersection, the lines slightly "overshoot," e.g.:

```
x   y
-24 20
-23 20
20  23
23  -23
-22 -23
-23 23
-24 24
```

The actual file has hundreds of coordinates. I need to calculate the area of the polygon. I tried using splancs areapl, but I believe it's over-estimating the area because of the overshoot. I need to either find a way to calculate the area and ignore the overshoot or crop the data so that it does not overshoot. I am new to R and am not super familiar with it. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how this is a programming question. What you're looking for is a mathematical approach to fix your "poor" data. Once that's solved you can just apply the [formula to calculate the area of a convex polygon](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm).

Comment: Well I am specifically looking for a way to do this in R. Maybe even something that will identify the point of intersection that I can use to crop the data.

Comment: Yes, but first, you need to know what you want to do in R before writing the code. I'm not saying you won't get an answer here, but ideally you'd already have the mathematical solution and then ask for help on the *R implementation*.

Comment: Oh and by the way, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087772/create-polygon-from-set-of-points-distributed/26089377#26089377). Your solution may lie on smoothing the polygon.

Comment: I will post on a math forum as well, and in the future will start there. I would like to keep this up here for now just in case someone has an idea.

Comment: I gave it a try but it still leaves the extra bits. Hopefully the math forum would have some suggestions. Thank you for your help!