# Rasterizing coordinates for an irregular polygon changes original shape

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, smoothing, rasterize

I am trying to smoothen the edges of an irregular polygon in R, namely to turn its sharp corners into round edges. I am trying to do this using `smoothr::smooth`, but this function operates on objects from packages `sf` or `sp` while all I have is a set of coordinates. Somehow, the result of turning my `data.frame` into a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object (an object class from package `sp`) is a rectangle whose limits are the extreme limits of the original polygon. Does anyone know how to turn my set of coordinates in an object of a class compatible with `smoothr::smooth` while maintaining the original polygon shape? Here is what I did, partially following instructions at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087772/create-polygon-from-set-of-points-distributed) page:

```
rm(list=ls()) # my compulsive habit of making sure R's memory is a clean slate

# Example dataset:
dd <- data.frame(
        Lon = c(18.95379, 18.82409, 18.58987, 18.80541, 18.92427, 19.00264),
        Lat = c(-32.42492, -32.32498, -31.89642, -31.73606, -32.16217, -32.37052)
        )

plot(0,0,
    xlim=c(18.5,19.1), ylim=c(-32.5,-31.6), 
    xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude"
    )
polygon(dd[,"Lon"],dd[,"Lat"], border="red")

# To make it smooth I plan on using
library(smoothr)
# But smoothr:: smooth works on objects from packages sf or sp so I need to  convert dd.
#convert to spatial points
library(sp)
coordinates(dd) = ~Lon + Lat
# convert to raster
library(raster)
rr <- raster::raster(dd)
#convert raster to polygons
sp = rasterToPolygons(rr, dissolve = T)
map(sp, add=T, col="green", fill=F)
# somehow my irregular polygon turned into a rectangle.
sps <- smooth(sp, method = "ksmooth", smoothness=5)
# this works, but of course is only rounding the corners of sp
map(sps, add=T, col="blue", fill=F)
```

[image]

In red is my original polygon from the `data.frame dd`, in green is object `sp`, in blue is the smooth version of `sp`, `sps`. Function `smooth` does the job, the problem is somewhere in the conversion of `dd` into an `sp`-compatible object. I suspect the problem is caused by `raster()` but I am not sure why or of how to fix it.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've used `sf` because I personally find that much easier:

```
library(sf)
library(smoothr)

# Example dataset:
dd <- data.frame(
  Lon = c(18.95379, 18.82409, 18.58987, 18.80541, 18.92427, 19.00264),
  Lat = c(-32.42492, -32.32498, -31.89642, -31.73606, -32.16217, -32.37052)
)

# cast to polygon, use multipoint first though.   
polygon <- as.matrix(dd) %>%
  sf::st_multipoint() %>%
  sf::st_cast("POLYGON")

#  smooth polygon
polygon_smoothed <- smoothr::smooth(polygon, method = "ksmooth", smoothness = 0.5)

# plot to check
plot(polygon, col = "red")
plot(polygon_smoothed, col = "blue", add = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/202536_7a122ff56e9f4062b6b012d9921afd80.html

```
# Example dataset:
dd <- data.frame(
        Lon = c(18.95379, 18.82409, 18.58987, 18.80541, 18.92427, 19.00264),
        Lat = c(-32.42492, -32.32498, -31.89642, -31.73606, -32.16217, -32.37052)
        )       
plot(0,0,
    xlim=c(18.5,19.1), ylim=c(-32.5,-31.6), 
    xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude"
    )
polygon(dd[,"Lon"],dd[,"Lat"], border="red")

library(sp)
p = Polygon(dd)
p2 = Polygons(list(p),1) # I believe this aggregates polygons, so in this case it doesn't do anything.
sp = SpatialPolygons(list(p2))
sps <- smooth(sp, method = "ksmooth", smoothness=0.7)
plot(sps, add=T, border="blue")
```