# How to draw Polygon for lots of lat/long coordinates and calculate surface are?

Tags: r, polygon, r-sp

I have the following data: https://ufile.io/p9s0le6g
...which consists of 485 lat/long observations. I ultimately want to calculate the surface area (in m2 or km2) of this figure. I wanted to create a polygon with the data points (the outer points) and then calculate the surface are. However, I cannot come up with a nice polygon.
My data points as coordinates look like:
[image]

I want a polygon which would look like that (or similarly):
[image]
Here is what I tried:

```
library(sp)
df <- read.csv('data.csv')
p = Polygon(df)
ps = Polygons(list(p),1)
sps = SpatialPolygons(list(ps))
plot(sps)
```

This results in (clearly not a nice polygon):
[image]
I also tried to implement the answer of [Create polygon from set of points distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087772/create-polygon-from-set-of-points-distributed) but this results in just a rectangular for me:
[image]

Anyone an idea how I can optimize my polygon to get a figure which looks like the outer shape of my data points and how to then calculate the surface are of that optimized polygon?

Comment: You could subset the points that fall on the outermost area and create a polygon from these coordinates. Subsetting could work by identifying the points that do not have a nearest neighbor (within a given range) to the south/east/west/north.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `concaveman` and `sf` we can create a concave hull around your set of points:

```r
library(sf)
library(concaveman)

pts <- st_as_sf(df, coords=c('LONG','LAT'), crs=4326 )

conc <- concaveman(pts)

conc %>% st_area()
# 4010443 [m^2]
```

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=pts, col = 'red', pch=3)  +
  geom_sf(data = conc, fill = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I needed

Comment: @Mansi `conc` is an `sf` polygon. It should be possible to cast to points using `st_cast(conc, 'POINT')`

Comment: Thank you, I realised that my understanding of the concaveman output was a bit faulty. But thank you for your help, @Chris

Answer (score 4):

Consider using functions from the excellent {sf} package instead of the older {sp}.

Such as this example, built on `sf::st_convex_hull`

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

points <- read_csv("data.csv") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("LONG","LAT"), crs=4326)


polygon <- st_union(points) %>%  # unite the points to 1 object
  st_convex_hull() # calculate the convex hull

# verify the results by drawing a map
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = points, col = "red", size = 2, pch = 4) +
  geom_sf(data = polygon, col = "grey45", fill = NA)


# as a bonus: area of the polygon  
area <- st_area(polygon)
area
```

[image]