# Draw polygons around coordinates in R

Tags: r, maps, spatial, r-sf

I have clusters of points from different datasets collected in different geographical regions. I'd like to plot the spatial extent of each region on a map, for which I need a single polygon per region. I can find commands to convert points to polygons by "connecting the dots", but none by drawing an outline (the geometric method isn't terribly important since this is just for plotting). Here's a reprex to generate a simplified dataframe like the one I'm using, for points in Norway, Alaska, and the continental US:

```
nor_lat <- c(72.117, 71.05, 71.717, 71.167, 71.817, 72.333, 71.25, 70.917, 
  70.85, 70.933)
nor_lon <- c(33.217, 30.333, 26.3, 22.333, 22.333, 22.333, 18.517, 20.133, 
             21.333, 19.917)
us_lat <- c(41.283333, 41, 40.95, 40.95, 38.683333, 40.783333, 40.733333, 
            40.516667, 38.566667, 41.266667)
us_lon <- c(-71.116667, -70.733333, -70.583333, -70.483333, -74.816667, 
            -70.5, -70.566667, -70.266667, -74.85, -71.366667)
ak_lat <- c(58.015, 57.67167, 57.33833, 56.685, 56.99333, 57.31667, 57.65, 
            57.99667, 58.32167, 58.33333)
ak_lon <- c(-158.31667, -158.36, -158.41, -159.76, -159.72333, -159.66333, 
            -159.64167, -159.605, -159.54, -160.72167)
nor_dat <- data.frame(lat=nor_lat, lon=nor_lon)
us_dat <- data.frame(lat=us_lat, lon=us_lon)
ak_dat <- data.frame(lat=ak_lat, lon=ak_lon)
nor_dat$region <- "nor"
us_dat$region <- "us"
ak_dat$region <- "ak"
dat <- rbind(nor_dat, us_dat, ak_dat)
```

For the object `dat`, I'd like to generate a simple polygon around the points in each `region`, using sf if possible. (I'm not too worried about figuring out how to iterate over the regions, but I can't even figure out how to draw a polygon around one set of points!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw Polygon for lots of lat/long coordinates and calculate surface are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474365/how-to-draw-polygon-for-lots-of-lat-long-coordinates-and-calculate-surface-are)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

hulls <- dat %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat")) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_convex_hull()
plot(hulls)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `sf` and `dplyr` for "geocomputation" and filtering, `tmap` and `tmaptools` for visualization.

Please find the following reprex.

**Reprex**

- Convert the `dataframe` "dat" into a `sf` object

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)

sf_use_s2(TRUE)

dat_sf <- st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
```

- Compute a smoothed enveloping polygon for each set of points in each area

```r
conv_nor <- st_simplify(st_buffer(st_convex_hull(st_union(st_geometry(filter(dat_sf, region == "nor")))), dist = 15000), dTolerance = 5000)
conv_us <- st_simplify(st_buffer(st_convex_hull(st_union(st_geometry(filter(dat_sf, region == "us")))), dist = 15000), dTolerance = 5000)
conv_ak <- st_simplify(st_buffer(st_convex_hull(st_union(st_geometry(filter(dat_sf, region == "ak")))), dist = 15000), dTolerance = 5000)
```

- Visualization: Overview

```r
tm_shape(dat_sf)+
  tm_dots(size = 0.2, col = "black", shape = 21, alpha = 0.3)+
  tm_shape(conv_nor)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_shape(conv_us)+
  tm_borders(col = "blue", lwd = 2)+
  tm_shape(conv_ak)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```

[image]

- Visualization: detailed views

```r
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "nor"), bbox = bb(conv_nor, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_nor)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'nor' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0.85, "bottom"))
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "us"), bbox = bb(conv_us, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_us)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'us' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0., "top"))
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "ak"), bbox = bb(conv_ak, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_ak)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'ak' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0.75, "top"))
```

[image]

- Detailed views with background

Finally, if you want some contextual background, you can use the `tmap_mode("view")` which call `leaflet` - apparently you work on the marine environment ;-)

```r
tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "nor"), bbox = bb(conv_nor, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_nor)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'nor' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0.85, "bottom"))
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "us"), bbox = bb(conv_us, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_us)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'us' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0., "top"))
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(filter(dat_sf, region == "ak"), bbox = bb(conv_ak, ext = 1))+
  tm_dots(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5)+
  tm_shape(conv_ak)+
  tm_borders(col = "gray", lwd = 2)+
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, title = "'ak' area", 
            title.size = 1.5, title.position = c(0.75, "top"))
```

[image]

```r
tmap_mode("plot")
#> tmap mode set to plotting
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Please, let me know if the rendering is as you wish. Cheers.