# How to reorder x,y coordinate points to form a closed loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a set of points which outline a map region. I want to use these points to define a polygon that I can plot with ggplot using the simple features (sf) library. However, the points are out of order, so a line connecting them does't form a closed shape. I have tried both geom_line and geom_path. Is there any way I might be able to get these re-organized without having to manually order them?

In the reproducible example below, "good circle" is what I want, while "bad circle" is what I have. They include all of the same x,y points, but due to bad circle being out of order I can't make a closed figure.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

x_coords <- rad * cos(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
y_coords <- rad * sin(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
perimeter <- as.matrix(rbind(cbind(x_coords, y_coords), c(x_coords[1], y_coords[1])))
perimeter

good_circle = st_multipolygon(list(list(perimeter)))
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = good_circle, fill = "blue") + ggtitle("good circle")
```

[image]

What I have looks like this:

```
bad_circle <- slice(data.frame(perimeter), sample(1:n()))
ggplot(bad_circle, aes(x = x_coords, y = y_coords)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + ggtitle("bad circle")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose you a different approach. Instead of reordering points, you can create a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) around your un-ordered points and get the polygon.

Although sf has a function for this (`sf::st_convex_hull()`) I usually prefer the results of the package `concaveman`, that are also compatible with `sf` objects. See:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)


rad <- 1

x_coords <- rad * cos(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
y_coords <- rad * sin(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
perimeter <- as.matrix(rbind(cbind(x_coords, y_coords), c(x_coords[1], y_coords[1])))
perimeter
#>            x_coords      y_coords
#>  [1,]  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
#>  [2,]  8.660254e-01  5.000000e-01
#>  [3,]  5.000000e-01  8.660254e-01
#>  [4,]  6.123032e-17  1.000000e+00
#>  [5,] -5.000000e-01  8.660254e-01
#>  [6,] -8.660254e-01  5.000000e-01
#>  [7,] -1.000000e+00  1.224606e-16
#>  [8,] -8.660254e-01 -5.000000e-01
#>  [9,] -5.000000e-01 -8.660254e-01
#> [10,] -1.836910e-16 -1.000000e+00
#> [11,]  5.000000e-01 -8.660254e-01
#> [12,]  8.660254e-01 -5.000000e-01
#> [13,]  1.000000e+00 -2.449213e-16
#> [14,]  1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00

bad_circle <- slice(data.frame(perimeter), sample(1:n()))

# sf + concaveman

poly <- bad_circle %>%
  # to sf
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x_coords", "y_coords")) %>%
  # w/ concaveman
  concaveman::concaveman()

# A polygon
poly
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -1 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>                         polygons
#> 1 POLYGON ((-0.866 -0.5, -1 1...


# Plot

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = poly, fill = "blue") +
  ggtitle("poly w/ concaveman")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: aww... you beat me by like 10 minutes :) I raise an imaginary glass of beer in a general south westerly direction!

Comment: Cheers mate! It may be the first time I am faster than you here on SF

Comment: Thanks so much! convexman was exactly what I needed to solve my problem. The shapes I have are a good deal more complicated than the circle example, so I checked out the documentation and played around with different values for concavity and length_threshold until I got a line matching my shape.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the points to polar coordinates:

```
polar = data.frame(r = sqrt(bad_circle$x_coords^2 + bad_circle$y_coords^2), theta = atan2(bad_circle$y_coords, bad_circle$x_coords))
```

Then plot the points in the order of the angle:

```
plot(bad_circle[order(polar$theta),], type="l")
```

To keep the order in ggplot, use geom_path:

```
ggplot(bad_circle[order(polar$theta),], aes(x = x_coords, y = y_coords)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

Comment: Thankyou for proposing this solution! If I had shapes centered at 0 it would work very well. My MRE here might be a little too minimal as many of my shapes are off zero and thus run into some trouble.

Comment: If the data aren't centered at 0, you can always recentre them before converting to polar by subtracting the average x and y, respectively in the polar conversion function.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you describe could be interpreted as finding a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

This is not an uncommon operation, and as such there are standardized tools in `{sf}` environment to achieve it (although I must say that converting points to polar and then finding r and theta as @user1505631 suggested is quite inventive).

My proposal would be to first convert your many individual points to a single multipoint object via a `sf::st_union()` call and then find its convex hull via `sf::st_convex_hull()` call.

It is possible - especially in case of points that are not so conveniently spaced as your circle - that a convex hull would not quite fit the expectations; in such case consider also `concaveman::concaveman()`; for an example of that in action (and differences between the convex and concave hulls on real world data) have a look at [How to draw Polygon for lots of lat/long coordinates and calculate surface are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474365/how-to-draw-polygon-for-lots-of-lat-long-coordinates-and-calculate-surface-are)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

rad <- 5

x_coords <- rad * cos(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
y_coords <- rad * sin(seq(0, (2 * pi), (pi / 6)))
perimeter <- as.matrix(rbind(cbind(x_coords, y_coords), c(x_coords[1], y_coords[1])))

bad_circle <- slice(data.frame(perimeter), sample(1:n())) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x_coords", "y_coords"))

hull <- bad_circle %>% 
  st_union() %>% 
  st_convex_hull()

plot(hull, col = "gray")
plot(bad_circle, col = "red",  pch = 4, add = T)
```

[image: good circle with points in red]

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It was really helpful to see an example of using the convex hull. Your suspicion that the actual set of points is a good deal more complicated than the circle is right, I found that convexman was the best to fit my shapes (the actual shapes represent white matter tracts in the brain).